# replace string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, preg-replace

I have text inside "textarea" and I was trying to remove the text between: `<textarea></textarea>` using replace function with some regex. here is what I did so far:

```
x = '<TEXTAREA style="DISPLAY: none" id=test name=test>teeeeessst!@#$%&*(LKJHGFDMNBVCX</TEXTAREA>';

x.replace('/<TEXTAREA style="DISPLAY: none" id=test name=test>.*</TEXTAREA>/s','<TEXTAREA style="DISPLAY: none" id=test name=test></TEXTAREA>');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably want something like this:

```
x.replace(/(<textarea[^>]*>)[^<]+(<\/textarea>)/img, '$1$2');
```

This will replace things case-insensitively within multi-line strings and avoiding greedy matches of things like ".*"

Comment: thanks man this one works like charm..

really appreciated :)

Comment: The `m` modifier only matters if there are anchors (`^` or `$`) in the regex.

Answer (score 1):

First problem is that you've got your regex inside quotes.  It should just be /regex/ without quotes. Then you're going to have to put a backslash before the forward slash in the regex.

```
/<TEXTAREA style="DISPLAY: none" id=test name=test>.*<\/TEXTAREA>/
```

There's no regex flag "s", so I don't know what you thought it means but just drop it.

Comment: I really don't know how to use regex with javascript.
it seems like different from PHP.

Comment: Yes, it's different.  Not a *lot* different, but different.

Comment: You mean there's no `s` flag in *JavaScript* regexes.  To get the same effect we usually use replace the `.` with `[\s\S]`, but in this case `[^<]` is more appropriate, as @Eric showed.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Eric's method, or use more general regexp.

```
var re =/(\<[^<]+\>)[^<]+(<\/[^<]+>)/;

x = x.replace(re, '$1$2');
```

You can use [this tool](http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/regtest.htm) to have a test. The result should be output to testarea.